# Python always getting invalid syntax error

Tags: python

I dont understand why i get always a invalid syntax error.
Can you please help?

```
def steigung(a,b,c,d,x):

Ausgabe= 3*a*x**2+2*b*x+c
Ausgabe2= 6*a*x+2*b

if Ausgabe >= 1:
    print("Die Funktion Steigt")
elif Ausgabe <= -1:
    print("Die Funktion Fällt")
elif Ausgabe=0 and Ausgabe2 > 0:
    print("Die Funktion hat ein lokales Minimum")
elif Ausgabe=0 and Ausgabe2 < 0:
    print("Die Funktion hat ein lokales Maximum")
elif Ausgabe=0 and Ausgabe2 = 0:
    print("die Funktion einen kritischen Punkt unbekannten Typs")


return print
```

Comment: Equality comparison is `==`. Your indentation is wrong.

Comment: and what is `return print` ?

Comment: @Arman: `return print` returns the `print`-function.

Comment: @Daniel , is it a use able action or it's just a miss functionality here?

Comment: @Arman: it is probably not useful, but also no syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an assignment to compare the values rather than using the comparison operator `==`. Also, I would refer to local variables using lowercase letters.
Finally, I don't get why you are returning the `print` function, remove that.

```
def steigung(a,b,c,d,x):

   ausgabe= 3*a*x**2+2*b*x+c
   ausgabe2= 6*a*x+2*b

   if ausgabe >= 1:
      print("Die Funktion Steigt")
   elif ausgabe <= -1:
      print("Die Funktion Fällt")
   elif ausgabe==0 and ausgabe2 > 0:
      print("Die Funktion hat ein lokales Minimum")
   elif ausgabe==0 and ausgabe2 < 0:
      print("Die Funktion hat ein lokales Maximum")
   elif ausgabe==0 and ausgabe2==0:
      print("die Funktion einen kritischen Punkt unbekannten Typs")
```